# How do I encode a query string containing forward slashes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, url

I need to pass a path as a parameter to a url e.g.
/Controller/Action/My-Path but My-Path contains forward slash e.g. /dir1/dir2/file.php
Is there any way of passing this path as a single parameter or do I need to break the path down as /Controller/Action/Param1/dir1/Param2/dir2/Param3/file.php. Some sample code would be appreciated

TIA  Ephraim

Answer (score 4):

You can use url view helper, e.g.:

```
    echo $this->view->url(
            array(
            'controller' => 'somecontroller',   
            'action' => 'someaction',    
            'path'=>'/dir1/dir2/file.php')
            );
```

This will result in:

```
public/somecontroller/someaction/path/%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Ffile.php
```

url view helper automatically uses url_encode to encode your parameters (see other anwser).

Comment: Embed in <a href=
public/somecontroller/someaction/path/%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Ffile.php>link</a> and yiou get

Answer (score 0):

See: https://www.php.net/url_encode

so you would do:

```
$param = url_encode("/this/parameter/file");
```

Comment: Embed in <a href=
public/somecontroller/someaction/path/%2Fdir1%2Fdir2%2Ffile.php>link</a> and you get ../path//dir1/dir2/file.php